# Zoned bar with UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, draw, uibezierpath

I created a zoned bar.
However, I don't really understand how to add the distance between the zones.

```
let zones = [Zone(color: .lightGray, height: 0.3), Zone(color: .gray, height: 0.3), Zone(color: .darkGray, height: 0.4)]
 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        var savedValue: CGFloat = 0
        
        zones.forEach { zone in
            let rectangle = UIBezierPath(rect:
                CGRect(
                    x: .zero,
                    y: savedValue * bounds.size.height,
                    width: bounds.size.width,
                    height: CGFloat(zone.height) * bounds.size.height
                )
            )
            zone.color.setFill()
            rectangle.fill()
            savedValue += CGFloat(zone.height)
        }
    }
```

[image: red arrow]  [image] [image]

```
  red arrow     I want to be so      now
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add the distance between the zones"? Is there anything wrong with your code? What's the expected output? What's the actual output?

Comment: Where are the red arrows. Need to insert spacing between colors.